# Duplicate question with answers for newer version

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, language-versions

So I noticed [this Java question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022822), which is a duplicate of [this older question from 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205555).

However, there's now a better answer for the question, with the release of Java 8 a year and a half ago. And someone had provided that answer on the newer question.

The older question also had that answer, but buried after about 15 higher-ranked answers.

Marking the newer question a duplicate seemed a mistake.

But my action may have also been a mistake, and I'd like some feedback and some suggestions on what the appropriate action would be.

The older question addressed versions prior to Java 8. The leading answer on the new question addressed Java 8. Thinking that was a logical division, I added "in Java 8" to the title of the newer question, without knowing what version the OP was using.

What would have been an appropriate action?